# jQuery regex get from url

Tags: jquery, regex

I read regex documentation but don't understand how to that i want.

i have urle `http://testhermes.tumblr.com/post/108728110699/hermes-instagram-photo-sit-back-and-relax?index=1` like this wit regex i want take numbers after post  "108728110699" and index= "1"

can you help me please.
thank you.

Comment: window.location.search gives you the querystring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var url = "http://testhermes.tumblr.com/post/108728110699/hermes-instagram-photo-sit-back-and-relax?index=1";
url = url.match(/\d+/g);
alert(url[0]);  //108728110699
alert(url[1]); //1
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: and how can i Take the numbers separately?